# Cannot increase work_mem above 1GB using PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows Server

Tags: windows, postgresql, memory, database-performance

I would like to tweak the postgres config for use on a Windows server. Here is my current posgresql.conf file: http://pastebin.com/KpSi2zSd

I would like to increase `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem`, but if I raise the values above 1GB I get this error when starting the service:

[image]

Nothing is added to the log files (at least not in data\pg_log). How can I figure out what is causing the issue (increase logging)? Could the have anything to do with issues management between windows and postgres?

Here are my server specs:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (64 bit)
- Intel CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50 GHz
- 512 GB RAM
- PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Under Windows the `work_mem` is limited to 1GB - I don't know why and I don't think there is a workaround. But why do you think you need more than 1GB **work_mem**?. Are you aware that **every** query can request that memory **multiple** times? So you _could_ have a single query requesting 10GB of memory.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this constraint. I have a lot of RAM and few users using the database for ETL and pre-processing / aggregating data. At the moment postgres is using barely any RAM - I would much rather it used 100GB when necessary if this speeds up creating indexes and aggregating data.

Comment: You could increase `shared_buffers`. But the "unused" RAM isn't really "unused". It will be used by Windows to cache the data from the file system - make sure you adjust `effective_cache_size` to match this setup.

Comment: The limit for `work_mem` is actually 2GB though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Windows the value for `work_mem` is limited to 2GB (even on a 64bit system) - there is no workaround as far as I know.

I don't know why you couldn't set it to 1GB though. Maybe the sum of `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem` has another limit I am not aware of.

Setting `work_mem` that high *by default* is usually not a good idea. With 512GB RAM and just 10 users this *might* work, but keep in mind that the amount of `work_mem` is requested by a statement for every sort, group or hash operation in a single query. So you could have a statement requesting this amount of memory 15 or 20 times.

You don't need to change this in `postgresql.conf` - this can be changed dynamically if you know that the following query will benefit from a large work_mem, by running:

```
set session work_mem='2097151';
```

If you use a higher number, you'll get an error message telling you the limit:

> ERROR: 2097152 is outside the valid range for parameter "work_mem" (64 .. 2097151)

---

Even if Postgres isn't using all the memory, it still benefits from it. Postgres (unlike e.g. Oracle) relies heavily on the filesystem cache rather than doing all the caching itself. Values for `shared_buffers` beyond roughly 8GB rarely show any benefit.

What you *do* need to tell Postgres is how much memory the operating system usually uses for caching, by setting `effective_cache_size` to the appropriate value. Postgres doesn't *use* that for caching, but it influences the planner's choice to e.g. prefer an index scan over a seq scan if the index is likely to be in the file system cache.

You can see the current size of the file system cache in the Windows task manager (or e.g. ProcessExplorer)

Answer (score 1):

as described above, in windows it is more beneficial to rely on the OS cache.
If you use RAMMAP from sysinternals (Microsoft) you can see exactly what is being used by postgres in the OS cache, and hence how much is actually cached to it.